# Nodejs EMFILE Error working with pm2 and socket.io

Tags: node.js

I have got this error when working with nodejs and pm2:

```
connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo EMFILE localhost:27017]
0|app      |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/ride4youco/public_html/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
0|app      |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
0|app      |     at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
0|app      |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/ride4youco/public_html/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
0|app      |     at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
0|app      |     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
0|app      |     at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
0|app      |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ride4youco/public_html/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
0|app      |     at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
0|app      |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

While I am using node with express and socket.io
Maybe someone know what causes this?

This is the app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var compression = require('compression');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var session = require('express-session');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src/'));

app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());

app.use('/rides', require('./routes/ridesServer'));
app.use('/user', require('./routes/userServer'));
app.use('/offers', require('./routes/offersServer'));
app.use('/notifications', require('./routes/notificationsServer'));

server.listen("8080", function() {
  console.log("Connected to db and listening on port 8080");
});
```

Everything worked very good for a full month, this started to happen when tried to work with redirect 301 or maybe some NEW socket functions.
I say NEW, because I have worked with socket function for a full month, and everything was okay.. I have also comment those socket lines and this still not working..

I have to mention that will work again after 5min, then after some mins it will not work again..

I also got this error:

```
0|app      | Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/home/ride4youco/public_html/src/fonts/open-sans/opensanshebrew-regular-webfont.woff'
```

Comment: Too many open files is a pretty serious problem but it seems unrelated to this code. This part doesn't open any files. Something else does and is probably not closing them properly.

Comment: But it worked very good until Ive played a bit with the redirect 301..

Comment: I know how that feels, but this code doesn't open files. You may have a coincidental regression somewhere else.

Comment: This is maybe something with socket.io, when I remove this, everything is okay, this is the socket io line in app.js: var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

Comment: I have edited this

Answer (score 0):

Once I have added this line to app.js before all routing:

```
var fs = require('graceful-fs');
```

Things got working again. Hope it will keeps like that.